# Swift Compiler Error on New Mac

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I just copied my project over to a new mac (xcode/iOS up-to-date). However, I'm getting `Swift Compiler Error` when I try to build/run.

```
<unknown>:0: error: opening import file for module 'Swift': Permission denied
```

**Looks like its an issue with my bridger file**. So I tried the following

1. Deleted the old reference under Build Settings > Swift Compiler > Objective-C Bridging Header
2. Added a new objective-c file and created a new bridge.

However, the error still persists.
Any clue what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking the user permissions of your files and add your new user as the owner of those files. Make sure it applies to all descendent items using the finder get info Owner permissions

Comment: I just gave all users Read & Write access and applied it to all enclosing files. Restarted XCode. Still not compiling.

Comment: Don't forget to make your new user is set as the owner of them

Comment: It is swift and unfortunately it is not working. I can't quite send it since it's not my personal project.

Comment: Ok I don't know what else can be causing this issue. Try using the original  computer to zip the folder before moving it to the destination mac

Comment: I think it is a permission issue. How can I make sure the user is set to owner? I set the current user with access to "read&write". The option is greyed out. (I assume that means the user is already the owner)

Comment: I recursively applied ownership to all files `sudo chown -Rv username directory` Did not help

Comment: Yes if you are already the owner "make me the owner" shows dimmed

Answer (score 0):

Possibly one of the most inefficient solutions: I ended up creating a new project and importing all files, frameworks, plist settings, build settings over. Took a while (the project is fairly large), but ended up compiling.

Comment: What a pain but at least it worked. Happy coding now :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the "Framework Search Paths" was wrong. There was absolute paths from another computer.